# How to do refund in Stripe PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make a refund in Stripe.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_mhsaHbKAtvieiWSDSvc7qFwJ");

$re = \Stripe\Refund::create(array(
  "charge" => "ch_19DVSLIAgNbxQsQZfjhoP8jQ"
));
```

But it did not work. Will some one guide me what wrong I am doing. 
I'm getting this error:
`Fatal error: Class 'Stripe_ApiResource' not found`

Thanks Folks

Comment: What exactly was the error?

Comment: Consider adding more information to your question. It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Are you fully importing all the classes?

Comment: Yes sir.. i have all libraries function...

Comment: Your error is saying it can't find a class, are you loading through composer?

Comment: Yes i am using composer..

Comment: Does anything else in Stripe work? If you could give a bit more of an explanation as to what exactly is happening instead of simple responses people would be able to help you a lot more. Have you sorted the auto loaded, cleared the config cache etc?

Comment: i do payment with stripe Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => $_POST['amount'],
                                "currency" => "usd",
                                "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
        "description" => $_POST['email']));                                                                           And payment successfully done.. but when i do refund with stripe i have problem...

Comment: Composer update doesn't fix it?

Comment: Probably worth including part of your composer file so people can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done with following solution.

```
$ch = Stripe_Charge::retrieve('ch_19DReJIAgNbxQsQZsBTh85Ka');
$ch->refunds->create(array('amount' => 100));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do refund as below

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_mhsaHbKAtvieiWSDSvc7qFwJ");

 $refund = \Stripe\Refund::create([
            'charge' => 'ch_19DVSLIAgNbxQsQZfjhoP8jQ',
            'amount' => 1000,  // For 10 $
            'reason' => 'refund'
        ]);

$balanceTransaction = \Stripe\BalanceTransaction::retrieve($refund->balance_transaction);
```